# MongoDB: Optimized search of multiple collections

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

I would like to improve my search method - which should be case insensitive. In my setting there are five different collections and I want to search for the `title` field of them.
Also I need to get also partial results (minimum 3 characters).

**Example**

```
// Collection 1
{ title: 'Sample' },
{ title: 'Another sample' }
{ title: 'This is an example' }

// Collection 2
{ title: 'Something else' },
{ title: 'A sample document' }
{ title: 'This is another example' }
```

1. `Ample`: All documents, except the first one of 2nd collection
2. `Sample`: The first two documents of collection 1 and the second of collection 2
3. `another`: Second document of collection 1
4. `is`: Should not give any result (<3 characters)

So far I did it with this

```
db.collection.find({ title: new RegExp(value, 'i') }).fetch()
```

...for each collection and merge the results into one array.

But I think this is not optimal as a regex is used and also all documents have to be searched by the db.

So I turned to use a fulltext search. I added a index to `title` and tried this:

```
db.collection.find({ $text: { $search: value } }).count()
```

But then `Samp` don't even gives me the first document.

And last but not least I don't know how to perform a search for all five collections to get all matches as one result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what MongoDB manuals says:

> For case sensitive regular expression queries, if an index exists for
>   the field, then MongoDB matches the regular expression against the
>   values in the index, which can be faster than a collection scan.
>   Further optimization can occur if the regular expression is a “prefix
>   expression”, which means that all potential matches start with the
>   same string. This allows MongoDB to construct a “range” from that
>   prefix and only match against those values from the index that fall
>   within that range.
>
> A regular expression is a “prefix expression” if it starts with a
>   caret (^) or a left anchor (\A), followed by a string of simple
>   symbols. For example, the regex /^abc.*/ will be optimized by matching
>   only against the values from the index that start with abc.

and this is important:

> For case insensitive regular expression queries, these queries
>   generally cannot use indexes effectively.

For your case you should use `$regex` keyword and use `.*` in your `value` var.

```
db.collection.find({ $text: { $regex: value, options: 'i' } }).count()
```

For your last question - I don't see any other solution, than doing `find` on every collection, passing results through `.forEach` and appending the results to the same one array/object.

Comment: the query shared by you is throwing an error  

`Error: error: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Missing expected field \"$search\"",
 "code" : 4,
 "codeName" : "NoSuchKey"
}`